# iOS YUV convert to RGB is a little reddish than AVPlayer

Tags: ios, video, codec, gpuimage

We use standard matrix from wikipedia

```
const GLfloat kColorConversion709[] = {
     1,       1,       1,
     0,   -.21482, 2.12798,
     1.28033, -.38059,       0,
};
```

but result is a little reddish than AVPlayer.

The format is BT.709

Comment: **(1)** What is the question though? All you've said is that the Wikipedia formula is more reddish than AVPlayer. You could improve this question with some example images of: your **input**, the expected **result** and finally your current **code result** (is it the one that is more reddish?). Your question could then become about achieving the expected result using the above matrix.